# SpaceOverhead and Performance Using MultiThread for Produer and Consumer differ a lot ,can't figure it out why

Tags: java, multithreading, overhead

Wrote two kind codes to simulate Producer and Consumer, although they implements the same funtion, the space overhead and performance diff. Why?

```
package ringBuffer.parallel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Producer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
        Producer mc = new Producer() ;
        Consumer cr = mc.new Consumer() ;
        cr.start() ;

        for (Integer j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> msgs = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>() ;
            for (Integer i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                msgs.put(i,j.toString()) ;
            }
            cr.addToMsgBuf(msgs);
        }

        try {
//              cr.waitUntilEmpty();
                cr.interrupt() ;                
                cr.join() ;   
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" last : "+ ( System.currentTimeMillis() -start));
        System.exit(0);
    }

    class Consumer extends Thread {
        int bufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        private byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        private Integer pos = 0;
        private Integer prePos = 0;
        String outputFile = "F:\\test\\ringBuf.txt";
        RandomAccessFile raf;
        StringBuffer sb = null;
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> cMsgs = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>() ;    ;

        public Consumer(){
            try {
                raf = new RandomAccessFile(outputFile, "rw");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                   while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                       synchronized (cMsgs){
                           while (cMsgs.isEmpty()) {
                               cMsgs.wait();
                           }
                           sb = new StringBuffer();
                           for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> v : cMsgs.entrySet()) {
                               sb.append(v.getKey()).append("-").append(v.getValue()).append("V") ;
                           }
                           cMsgs.clear() ;
                           cMsgs.notify() ;
                       }
                       sb.append("S");  
                       byte[] buf = sb.toString().getBytes();
                       int length = buf.length ;
                       pos = prePos + length ;
                       int bufPos = 0;
                       if (pos > bufferSize && prePos < bufferSize) {   
                            bufPos = bufferSize - prePos;
                            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, buffer, prePos, bufPos);  
                            prePos = pos = 0;
                            long fileLength = raf.length();  
                            raf.seek(fileLength);  
                            raf.write(buffer);  
                       }else 
                            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, buffer, prePos, length);  
                       if(bufPos==0){   
                           prePos = pos;
                       }else{    
                           System.arraycopy(buf, bufPos, buffer, prePos, length-bufPos); 
                           prePos = prePos +  length-bufPos ;
                           pos =prePos ;
                       }
                   }
                   long fileLength = raf.length();  
                   raf.seek(fileLength);  
                   raf.write(buffer, 0, prePos);  
                   raf.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }

        public void addToMsgBuf(LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> currentStepMsgs) {
             synchronized (cMsgs) {
                    try {
                        while(!cMsgs.isEmpty()){
                            cMsgs.wait() ;
                        }
                        cMsgs.putAll(currentStepMsgs);
                        cMsgs.notify() ;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
             }
        }

        public void waitUntilEmpty() throws InterruptedException{
            synchronized (cMsgs) {
                 while(!cMsgs.isEmpty()){
                      cMsgs.wait();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}

package ringBuffer.parallel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Producer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
        Producer2 pr = new Producer2() ;
        Consumer cr = pr.new Consumer() ;
        cr.start() ;
        for (Integer j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (Integer i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                sb.append(i.toString()).append("-").append(j.toString() + "V");
            }
            sb.append("S");
            byte[] msgs = sb.toString().getBytes();
//          System.out.println(msgs.length);
            cr.addToMsgBuf(msgs);
        }
        try {
            cr.interrupt() ; 
            cr.join() ;   
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" last : "+ ( System.currentTimeMillis() -start));
    }

    class Consumer extends Thread {
        int bufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        private byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        private Integer pos = 0;
        private Integer prePos = 0;
        String outputFile = "F:\\test\\ringBuf.txt";
        private int totalLength = 0;
        RandomAccessFile raf;

        public Consumer(){
            try {
                raf = new RandomAccessFile(outputFile, "rw");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        synchronized (buffer) {
                            while (pos > bufferSize ) { 
                                totalLength = totalLength + prePos ;
                                long fileLength = raf.length();     
                                raf.seek(fileLength);     
                                raf.write(buffer) ;  
                                prePos = prePos % bufferSize ;
                                pos = prePos;  
                                buffer.notify() ;   
                            }
                        }
                }
                totalLength = totalLength + prePos ;
                long fileLength = raf.length();    
                raf.seek(fileLength);    
                raf.write(buffer, 0, prePos) ;  
                raf.close() ;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void addToMsgBuf(byte[] buf) {
            if (buf == null || buf.length == 0)
                return;
            try {
                synchronized (buffer) {
                    pos = prePos + buf.length ;
                    int bufPos = 0 ;
                    while (pos > bufferSize && prePos<bufferSize) {  
                        bufPos = bufferSize-prePos ;
                        System.arraycopy(buf, 0, buffer, prePos, bufPos);  
                        prePos = bufferSize;
                        System.out.println("Wait Until there is enough space! ");
                        buffer.wait();
                    }
                    System.arraycopy(buf,bufPos, buffer, prePos, buf.length - bufPos);
                    prePos = pos ;
                    if(pos==0&&pos==prePos){  
                        prePos = prePos + (buf.length - bufPos) ;
                        pos = prePos ;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

form the code, it seems that Producer makes the smaller parallel granularity (save every time) than Producer2(save only when buffer is full), so it is slower. Did I understand it right ?

Comment: Your code is a mess and synchronization is partly missing (main) or done wrong (Consumer.run). So it is pointless to argue about performance or resource consumption.

Comment: Sorry, Can you point out which one ?   You mean  MsgWriter or MsgWriter 2 missing synchronization ?  I'm sorry but I really don't know where it  is wrong ...  I just want to use a circle buffer to implement Poducer and Consumer , then try the performance and resourse. Thanks!

Comment: For example: Your entire while-block is synchronized - so your threads will effectively run sequentially, not in parallel, of course.

Comment: Thanks,  I modified the while part , but I still don't know why Producer2 is quicker! Is the reason for memory releasing?  @isnot2bad

Comment: Sorry that I modify the code and the reason of performance is  that Producer makes the smaller parallel granularity (save every time) than Producer2(save only when buffer is full), so it is slower. Did I understand it right ? @isnot2bad